\if \else in conjunction with \AddToHook in book class and asymmetric pages difficult to set up
\documentclass[A4,english,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=170mm,bindingoffset=12.5mm,asymmetric,top=8mm,showcrop]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,cam,center]{crop} %
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage[nostamp]{draftwatermark}% nostamp=no watermark
\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{setspace}%
\usepackage{ifthen}\newboolean{first_answer_of_chapter}%
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}% 1mm=2.84526pt;
\setlength{\topmargin}{-25mm}%
\setlength{\headheight}{15mm}%
\setlength{\headsep}{4.2mm}%

\NewDocumentCommand \ParallelLines { O {blue!10!blue} }
{%
  \AddToHook{shipout/background}[ParallelLines]
  {%
\ifodd\value{page}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \setlength\unitlength{1mm}%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \put(22.6,18){\color{red!50!white}\vrule width 4pt height 200mm}%
                \put(147,18){\color{red!50!white}\vrule width 4pt height 200mm}%
    }}%
\else
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \put(9.8,18){\color{green!50!white}\vrule width 4pt height 210mm}%
                \put(138.4,18){\color{green!50!white}\vrule width 4pt height 210mm}%
    }}\fi%
}
}

\begin{document}

\ParallelLines

\chapter{A first chapter}
\section{A first (ODD) page is correct}

Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages. Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages. Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages. Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages. Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages. Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages. Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages. Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages. Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages.

\clearpage
\section{An (EVEN) page should show GREEN lines only}

Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages. Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages. Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages. 

\clearpage
\section{An (ODD) page should show RED lines only}

Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages. Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages. Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages.  

\clearpage
\section{An (EVEN) page}

Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages. Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages. Loads of text to illustrate the off-set odd and even pages.  

\end{document}


A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces or enclose words in backticks ```, they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

The left edge ot the text area is given by 1in+\oddsidemargin or 1in+\evensidemargin and the right edge is found by adding \textwidth.  Or you could just use \oddsidemargin-\evensidemargin to recalculate absolute coordinates.

I'm not familiar with \AddToShipoutPicture.  It looks like it is part of the eso-pic package, and is used by showframe and pdfpages.

you are telling geometry your paper in one size, crop your paper is another size and book your paper is the default (US letter) size. that probably does make setup a bit tricky.

don't set layout dimensions using conflicting approaches. if you set them manually, don't use geometry. if you use geometry, don't set them manually. geometry can't do its job if you sneak behind its back and interfere.

Thanks for your comments... I will experiment a little more.

I removed the two lines: \AddToShipoutPicture, and it then worked perfectly. I wish someone would undertake to explain in plain English what instruction like \AddToShipoutPicture and \AddToHook - that seem to have appeared quite recently - mean. Is there a textbook available that would help in this respect?

Try texdoc lthooks ltshipout, or search there: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base.
